# (OmNet++) Error in module X, when using SimuLTE

Tags: networking, mobile, system, distributed

For my thesis i need to simulate a scenario like the next one:

[Mobile Distributed System scenario, WHERE: Estación base = Base station, dispositivo móvil = mobile device (smartphone), celda = cell, red estática = static network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFXsH.png)

It's about group communication, where a smartphone (or more) can send discrete data (images and text) or continuous data (audio or video). Data is received first, in all the base stations and after that, data is sended to all the devices. The main focus of this project is the synchronization of the data, according to the causal dependencies between its generation till presentation (in a video conference: frames of a video shouldn't be played in a mobile device receiver, if this mobile device frame2 before frame1, considering frame2 was generated and sended after frame1 by another mobile device originally).

To develop this project, my thesis advisor asked me to use OmNet++. After investigate, i found that there is a module called SimuLTE to simulate cellular networks. With this, my idea is to reuse the code and focus in implementing a new algorithm to synchronize heteregeneous data.

The problem is that i'm trying to run SimuLTE (last version) examples in OmNet++ 5 with inet 3.4, after importing the inetLTE project (downloaded from simulte.com) and building everything, i get an error message. Already tested (what i found over here): OmNet++ 4.6, INET 3.4 and SimuLTE (for OmNet++ 4.6) and OmNet++ 4.4.1, INET 2.3 and SimuLTE 0.9.1

Inet Examples (not LTE) are working pretty well. I've been testing with different versions with the same result. Any idea of how to solve this? I get similar error messages with each example but i can't post more than 2 links.

[SimuLTE example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgfNi.png)

What would you recommend to continue working? Maybe a different module (not SimuLTE) or a different tool for this scenario (not OmNet++).

Thanks for your help!

Mike.

Comment: Nevermind, i solved this by using the following configuration:

Comment: OMNeT++ version 4.4.1
INET version 2.3.0

With SimuLTE revision a24d19d  on 26 Oct 2015

Debug mode to compile.

Sorry for multi-comment but pressing ENTER, sends msg.